# function type : cannot be decoded with abi.decode

Tags: types, ethereum, solidity

Function types are now available in solidity : I would like to abi.encode a function and then be able to abi.decode this function. The encoding works but the decoding doesn't

I have tried many different syntaxes as a parameter in abi.decode:

- `function`
- `function (uint,uint) external`

```
uint256 id;
address from;
function func (uint256 id1, uint256 id2) external  { } ; 
bytes memory data = abi.encode(id, from, func);
```

```
(uint orderId, address add, function (uint,uint) external thisFunc) = abi.decode(data, (uint,address,function));
```

When compiling the contract in truffle, I get the following error message:

- `=> Error message
  CompileError: ParsedContract.sol:88:158: ParserError: Expected primary expression.`

I would like to be able to get the function back in thisFunc variable after decoding

Comment: I don't think what you're specifically asking for is possible. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to encode information, here a function, and transport it as a bytes to another contract where I can decode it. Do you think it can't be done ? We can do this with all the other types (uint, address..), why couldn't we with this new type 'function' ?